# Перенос окна с xfce на хост

Tags: linux, xfce, xfce4

Порой необходимо получить удаленный доступ к серверу, поэтому иногда для рабочих задач использую рабочий стол xfce. Проблема заключается в том, что приложения запущенные на хосте не отображаются при подключении xfce. Так же и в обратную сторону.

Приложения работают и функционируют, но чтобы они запустились и окна отобразились в нужной мне системе, приходится либо выключать приложение(Через терминал, или через трей, если оно там есть) и заново запускать, тогда оно открывается именно в том месте(экране, пространстве, как еще назвать...), которое мне нужно. Самый простой способ уходя с работы ребутнуть хост и тогда при подключении к рабочему столу xfce я октрываю все приложения и их окну сразу появляются, но и так же придя на работу можно ребутнуть комп, чтобы открывать приложения уже на хосте.

**Сведения о системе предоставил в скриншоте.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К рабочему столу подключаюсь из под виндовс через RDP.

**Что я сделал?**

Облазил весь гугл и ничего не нашел для ответа на свой вопрос. Как будто только у меня одного такая проблема.

**Как я хочу чтобы мне помогли?**

Хотелось бы увидеть команду, которой можно перенести окно приложения с рабочего стола xfce на рабочий стол хоста и наоборот. Или же посоветовать другой аналог удаленного доступа к компьютеру на Linux.

**Почему xfce?**

Потому что нет необходимости обязательно логинится на хосте. При отключении света, обычном перезапуске хоста. Поэтому Anydesk и подобное не интересует.

Comment: Используйте RDP.

Comment: Или просто запускайте удалённо родными средствами X Windows (например, через `ssh -X -C`)

Comment: из под виндовс через RDP - через какой из серверов?